# XML de-serialization of child element through class in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to get the BK01 field of this XML file. I'm not sure what to do with the "FLOOR" element of the XML file and how to properly setup the classes to extract the BK01 value.

Method:

```
    public void GetBook()
{
    string path = directoryFile;

    XmlSerializer xmlSerial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LibraryCollection));
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
    LibraryCollection entity = xmlSerial.Deserialize(sr) as LibraryCollection;
    lblXMLName.Text = entity.BK01;  
}
```

Classes

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("LIBRARY")]

public class LibraryCollection
{

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("BK01")]

    public string BK01 { get; set; }
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LIBRARY>
    <FLOOR>
        <BK01 Value="Book1"/>
        <BK02 Value="Book2"/>       
    </FLOOR>
</LIBRARY>
```

Comment: Not taking into account Floor by the looks of it? Need an object for the deserialization to represent floor. Or use XPath on XElement to get to //Library/Floor/BK01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class hierarchy should be defined something like this:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("LIBRARY")]
public class LibraryCollection
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("FLOOR")]
    public Floor Floor { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Floor
{
    [XmlElement("BK01")]
    public BK Bk01 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("BK02")]
    public BK Bk02 { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class BK
{
    [XmlAttribute("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

You could then get the value like this:

```
LibraryCollection entity = xmlSerial.Deserialize(sr) as LibraryCollection;
lblXMLName.Text = entity.Floor.Bk01.Value;
```

Comment: This works great but I did need to add ".Value": ```entity.Floor.Bk01.Value;```

Comment: @Shane: Sure. I added this to the answer.